# Get a view field in the edit form

Tags: 7, views

I have a site that I have a form for users that they write down their personnal info's. I did a view, and then I made a field that has this view. Now what I want to do is to see this view field in the user's edit form. I can see all the fields that I want in the user's form but I cannot see the view field.

Answer (score 0):

Alter the form using `[hook_form_alter][1]`

```
<?php print views_embed_view('<Your view id>', $display_id = '<display id>'); ?>
```

Make that `display:none;` from CSS.

Comment: that is a good answer but there is not another way except this one?

Comment: I hope this module will achieve: Field Embed Views -> https://www.drupal.org/project/field_embed_views

Comment: yes i get this module but how i will use it in order to do what i need?

Comment: 1) Go to "Admin -> Modules" and enable module Field Embed Views
2) Then go to "Admin -> Structure-> Views -> Add new view" to define new view or use already create view. Configure exposed filters that will be embed in entity form
3) Add a field embed views to any entity, e.g. to a node. For that use the the usual "Manage fields" interface provided by the "field ui" module of Drupal, "Admin -> Structure-> Content types -> Article -> Manage fields". In field instance settings select View and Display.